# Android background image with shape

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to make a card background with rounded corners.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/card1" />
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dip"
                android:color="#225786" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image: Here is the result]
Any suggestion how to remove those corners? Or is possible at all ?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: I want to remove the square corners and leave only rounded corners. In the image the 90 degrees corners are present

Comment: you should rather try the default card view
https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html